# AWS Dynamodb Transactions library throwing error while Serrializing request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, transactions, jackson, amazon-dynamodb

How to fix this?

```
Failed to serialize request
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.transactions.Request$GetItem@24cab5b6
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting
getter definitions for property "null":
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue#getNULL(0
params) vs
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue#isNULL(0
params) (through reference chain:
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.transactions.GetItem["request"]->com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.GetItemRequest["key"])
    at
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.transactions.Request.serialize(Request.java:407)
~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson can't tell which getter is the "right" one. You can tell it to ignore one of the two methods:

```
public interface DynamoAttributeValueHack {
  @JsonIgnore
  public boolean isNull();

  @JsonIgnore
  public boolean isBOOl(); // You may need this as well depending on your AWS library version.
}

myMapper.addMixInAnnotations(AttributeValue.class, DynamoAttributeValueHack.class)
```